# Is there a way to create a second address against an existing private key in Ethereum?

Tags: ethereum

Is there a way to create another address, under a same private key. When I create a new account using `web3.eth.accounts.create()`, I understand that a new privatekey/address pair is created, but I am trying to add another 'address' which tags to the same private key, like in case of bitcoin.

Or does ethereum not work that way?

Answer (score 1):

In bitcoin, a single key can have two addresses - one for the compressed public key, and one for the uncompressed public key.

Ethereum only uses the uncompressed key, so a single private key will only lead to a single address.

You could use something like BIP39 to have a mnemonic based wallet that derived multiple private keys, each with its own address from a single source.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually using web3 js library to interact with ethereum node. Now, the idea you suggested wiht BIP39, is it like to have single master private key, and generate as many salts to append to the private key to create multiple privatekey/address pairs?